# How to stop mysqli_query from adding records with missing info?

Tags: php, mysql

I have form that subscribers enter their email address and this gets posted to mysql database. The problem is that if you visit the page, even without subscribing, a record is added to the database even without the required email address. Even worse, it seems to be adding records every three seconds. How can i stop this? Is there something wrong in my code.

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
// create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);
// check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("connection error: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo "connected";
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (empty($_POST['email'])) {
        $emailErr = "Email required";
    } else {
        $email = post_input($_POST['email']);
        $email = filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        if (!isset($emailErr)) {
            if (!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                $emailErr = "Invalid email address";
            }
        }
    }
}
// function to clean email
function post_input($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}
// select correct database
mysqli_select_db($conn, "mailinglist");
// query to insert email
$sql = "INSERT INTO subscribers (email) VALUES ('" . $_POST['email'] ."')";
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "Thank you for subscribing";
} else {
    echo "Error creating record: " . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
header('location: index.php');
mysqli_close($conn);
```

Comment: Your MySQL calls need to be inside of the `else` where you check for validity of the fields you require. As it is now it will get executed no mater what.

Comment: You need to use prepared statements. https://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input, especially that which comes from the client side. Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: Always `exit()` after `header('Location: ...');`

Comment: hi all, i;m very new at php, so would you be able to show me an example how i can prepare a parameterized prepared statement

Comment: @Ron117 for that you can check the links in he comment by Dharman

Answer (score -1):

Just check with the if statement if there is an email you can save and put saving to database into that if statement as below:

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
// create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);
// check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("connection error: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo "connected";

$emailErr = ''; //it is a good practice to initialize variable before its use.

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (empty($_POST['email'])) {
        $emailErr = "Email required";
    } else {
        $email = post_input($_POST['email']);
        $email = filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        if (!isset($emailErr)) {
            if (!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                $emailErr = "Invalid email address";
            }
        }
    }
}
// function to clean email
function post_input($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}
// select correct database
mysqli_select_db($conn, "mailinglist");

//if you have an email in $email and there is no
//error in $emailErr
if(!empty($email) && empty($emailErr)) {

    //insert it to the db.

    //THIS IS INSECURE WAY - Check links in comments!

    // query to insert email
    $sql = "INSERT INTO subscribers (email) VALUES ('" . $_POST['email'] ."')";
    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        echo "Thank you for subscribing";
    } else {
        echo "Error creating record: " . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
    }

}

mysqli_close($conn);
header('location: index.php');
exit();
```